# Can't figure out where extra CSS spacing is coming from

Tags: css, wordpress

I have migrated this WordPress site: http://www.frothers.com.au/ to this site: http://67.199.114.24/

For some reason the grey bar at the top of the new site is taller than the one on the old site.

I've inspected all the elements and I can't figure out why!

Thanks for the help,

Brandon

Comment: `responsive.css` are two different files. Check them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set .mymail-form {margin-bottom: 20px;} in the migrated index file, which is one of the reasons, and this should be deleted.

Another reason is the margin of form is different in migrated and original file app.css due to the order.

migrated:
[migrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTbFW.png)

original:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpI4e.png)

Comment: Changing <div class="large-12 columns"> to <div class="large-12 columns" style="height:40px"> solved the problem, but I still have no idea why the blue bar at the top was pushing the grey bar down...

Comment: At first you haven't set the height for the blue bar, and the real height is expanded by the height of child elements and vertical padding, while the vertical position of the next element (the gray bar) is affected by the vertical margin.

Comment: Yeah that's my real question... which of the child elements is causing it to expand?  I can't figure it out.

Comment: OK ran into a problem with this solution.  It kills the form when in responsive mode.  I need to know what child elements are pushing that blue bar out!

Comment: Well, the child element `<form>` of the blue bar `<div class="large-12 columns">` has a bottom margin, which is set as `1em` in Line 3455 of `app.css`, and `20px` in Line 184 of the index file, respectively. If you haven't set the height for the blue bar, these two lines might cause the expansion.

Comment: And I think you'd better post some screenshots here. I'm not sure whether the display in my browser is same as that in yours.

Comment: that was it!  Thanks.